# Grails won't read external config file?

Tags: grails, configuration-files, grails-2.3

I'm on Windows 7. Inside my Grails (2.3.6) app's `Config.groovy` file I have:

```
grails.config.locations = [
    "file:/etc/myapp/env.groovy"
]

// fizz.buzz is defined inside env.groovy
println "fizz.buzz=${fizz.buzz}"
```

At the root of my `D:\` drive:

```
etc/
    myapp/
        env.groovy
```

When I run `grails -Dgrails.env=local run-app` I get the following output:

```
fizz.buzz=[:]
```

What's going on here? Why can't Grails find my `env.groovy` file and/or read its properties?

My permissions:

[image]

Running `File('/etc/myapp/env.groovy').absolutePath` in the Groovy Console, I get:

```
Exception thrown

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ConsoleScript2.File() is
applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/etc/myapp/env.groovy]
Possible solutions: find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;),
with(groovy.lang.Closure), is(java.lang.Object), wait()
```

I also tried running my app and passing in the value for `fizz.buzz` on the command line via a switch like so:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=local -Dfizz.buzz="true" run-app
```

The result was the same. **Is it possible that the configs ARE being read in, but are just not available (caching, etc.) at the time that the `println` is running inside `Config.groovy`?**

Comment: where did you put this line:
`// fizz.buzz is defined inside env.groovy
println "fizz.buzz=${fizz.buzz}"`

If this is INSIDE of `Config.groov`y, you won't get output, try printing it from controller e.g
`render grailsApplication.config.fizz.buzz` 

Also make sure that user that is running grails has read permissions on `/etc/myapp/env.groovy`

Comment: Thanks @toske (+1) - however you are incorrect, `Config.groovy` is just like any other Groovy file and `println` statements **do** work from inside of it. The `println` you are referring to *is in fact* located inside my `Config.groovy` (try it out for yourself!). Also please see my updated question that contains my security permissions for the folder.

Comment: No you dont need to use backslashes. It should work. If you open a `groovyConsole` and execute `new File('/etc/myapp/env.groovy').absolutePath`, what did you get?

Comment: Thanks @matcauthon (+1) - I think we're starting to get somewhere. Please see my update which includes the output from the Groovy Console.

Comment: Give double slash and see if it works. Also test it with complete path: "C:\\<path>\\env.groovy"

Comment: It should be `new File('/etc/myapp/env.groovy').absolutePath `...including the `new` keyword

Comment: Thanks again @matcauthon (+1) - the output is `Result: D:\etc\myapp\env.groovy`.

Comment: Thanks @LalitAgarwal (+1) - but the output from the Groovy Console indicates Groovy has no problem finding my file, thoughts?

Comment: Can you try including like this: grails.config.locations = [
    "file:D:\\etc\\myapp\\env.groovy"
]

Comment: Thanks @LalitAgarwal (+1) - but that doesn't work either...

Comment: All - please see my update which shows `Config.groovy` failing to read my `fizz.buzz` property **off of the command line**. Might be chasing a red herring here with file system structure/permissions/etc.